# How to decompose the component that is influenced by X from time-series Y?

Tags: time-series, python, function, decomposition

There is a time series Y, which is the remaining part of the initial time series after removing the trend and seasonal periodic components. And there is also a time series X, which represents the change of water level.
(the data file is here: https://github.com/jacktang/dataset/tree/main/decompose)

I've read some papers and they talk about time series decomposing trend, season component, and few talk about how the decompose the remaining part. Time series Y is influenced by X, so I think time series Y should contains the influence of X and some noise.

I've analyzed the Y is not white noise:
[image]

I have visualized X and Y respectively, and compared them after standardization.
In addition, I plotted a scatter figure of Y vs X and its standardized version.
But I did not find an obvious relationship.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to decompose the influence of X on Y from time series Y?

Thanks!